# How can I solve svn error: "E200007: Cannot mix repository and working copy sources"

Tags: svn

I looked here for this issue, and none of the solutions pertain to me. The issue reported by other folks had a backslash in their command line, which I do NOT have. In my case, I'm trying to make a branch off a branch, so I did this:

```
- Existing branch: https://mysvn.repo.com/project/branch
- Created https://mysvn.repo.com/project/branch/private_branches folder in TurtoiseSVN explorer
- Tried svn cp -m "My private branch" https://mysvn.repo.com/project/branch https://mysvn.repo.com/project/branch/private_branches/my_private_branch
```

I get error in posts's title. Any pointers please?

Comment: Everything looks good. I do it like the with one exception; I have the message at the end. `svn cp https://mysvn.repo.com/project/branch https://mysvn.repo.com/project/branch/private_branches/my_private_branch -m "My private branch"`

Answer (score 6):

The command line is not seeing this as two URL's. Perhaps you have space in the URL, in which case you should encode that as %20 instead of entering a space?  Here is an example I just did using same syntax as you:

```
$ svn cp -m "Test branch" http://oneeight.tigris.org/svn/oneeight/trunk http://oneeight.tigris.org/svn/oneeight/branches/mptest1
Committed revision 24.
```

Comment: No space in the URLs, but thanks. In your example, where is the %20?

Comment: My example was just a simple one to show that the syntax you used was correct.  There is no space in my URL, so no %20

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem when issuing the SVN command from a script via a variable:

```
cmd=svn cp [...]
$cmd
```

The workaround I found is to issue the command directly from the script:

```
svn cp [...]
```

Perhaps this works for you/others as well.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and the solution was avoid using spaces in the message.
In my case it was because I was running the command on a grid and it gets wrapped automatically by a script that has some problems with spaces and double quotes.

Worked for me:

```
-m "My_private_branch"
```

Hope it works for you too.

PS: Haven't tried it but maybe -m 'My private branch' with single quotes does work.

Comment: Spaces in the message surrounded by double quotes is NOT an issue by any stretch of the imagination! Removing the spaces of a commit message in SVN or GIT is not going to change a thing; except make an difficult to read commit message if it is a long and detailed message.